# Postgresql-postgis dynamic library path

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to create a function in PostgreSql installed on a server but when a run the .sql function this is the error i get using PgAdminIII SQL queries:

> ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/librouting_dd": No such file or
>   directory

I have read the ['dynamic_library_path (string)'](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DYNAMIC-LIBRARY-PATH) in PostgreSql webpage but i don't understand how to write the correct path into my ubuntu system for PostgreSql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does pg_config --pkglibdir show? What do you have in your CREATE function, etc.

Comment: Hello. When i write _pg_config --pkglibdir_ ,the output is  /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib. And this is the CREATE in function :`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pgr_drivingdistance(sql text, source_id integer, distance double precision, directed boolean, has_reverse_cost boolean)
  RETURNS SETOF pgr_costresult AS
'$libdir/librouting_dd', 'driving_distance'
  LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 1
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION pgr_drivingdistance(text, integer, double precision, boolean, boolean)
  OWNER TO postgres;`

Comment: Note:The librouting_dd file that postgresql need to CREATE the function is copied from 9.3 version so when i write the path  /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib instead $libdir/librouting_dd, i get an EFL error.